# É possível tornar DropDownList "readonly" igual TextField

Tags: javascript, c#, asp.net-mvc

Eu entendo que o `DropDownList` já é *readonly*, já que não posso alterar os valores das opções, porém preciso manter o comportamento uniforme da tela.

Em modo consulta posso atribuir um *readonly* ao `TextBox` e o texto fica selecionável (com duplo **click**) mas inalterável. Quero permitir que o usuário possa também selecionar o texto do `DropDownList`, portanto não posso atribuir *disabled* ao campo.

```
@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeuValor, Model.MinhaLista, width: 100, renderContainer: false, showDisplayName: false, tipoUnidadeHtml: TipoUnidadeHtml.Porcentagem)
```

esse é meu código. Não posso adicionar o `(object)new { @disabled = "disabled" })` porque aí o duplo click não funciona.

Comment: Mas tens que por uma dropdown na parte de visualizacao? suponho que estejas a criar uma pagina de visualizacao do conteudo que foi editado, se assim é, podias por simplesmente o valor.

Comment: Sua pergunta está bem confusa. Me parece um filme que começo a assistir na metade e não vejo até o final. De que `DropDownList` você está falando? Cadê o seu código?

Comment: `@Html.DropDownListFor(m => m.MeuValor, Model.MinhaLista, width: 100, renderContainer: false, showDisplayName: false, tipoUnidadeHtml: TipoUnidadeHtml.Porcentagem)`
esse é meu código.. não posso adicionar o `(object)new { @disabled = "disabled" })` porque aí o _duplo click_ não funciona.

Comment: Edite a pergunta colocando lá o código, senão fica um pouco difícil de entender.

Answer (score 3):

Eu acho que o que pretendes não e possível.

Voltando um pouco ao comentário que já tinha feito porque não mostrar simplesmente o valor que o cliente selecionou? Adicionar um campo no *model* que devolve para a `View` com o `value` da `dropdown` em vez da `key`.

```
@Html.ValueFor(m => m.MeuValorString)
```

e caso tenha necessidade de submeter o *form*, e não perder esse valor. Adiciona a `Key` num `hiddenfor`

```
@Html.HiddenFor(m => m.MeuValor)
```

Comment: Ainda não consegui uma solução pra esse ponto, já pesquisei muito e até então é impossível. Pra contornar eu vou ter que fazer isso mesmo que você sugeriu (exibir o valor na consulta e o dropdown na edição) mas ainda não é o ideal.

Comment: sugiro te outra coisa, fazes um foreach a tua lista a imprimir uma tabela, e na class da row verificas se o valor corresponde ao selecionado e pintas essa row de outra cor

Comment: agradeço a sugestão mas não posso fazer isso porque o usuário deseja selecionar o valor (clicando duas vezes no campo) para copiar. Tive que criar um `TextBoxFor` e controlar quando devo exibir um ou outro.